# ubuntu 20.04.3 doesnt poweroff or restart or suspend

Tags: boot, drivers, suspend, shutdown, amdgpu

hp 15-ba021ax laptop newly switched from windows to ubuntu doesn't power-off after clicking on shut down, the power on LED and fans stay turned on,edited the file
*/etc/default/grub*

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force"
```

but that does nothing, clicking on restart also "shuts down" the laptop with fan and power led on and doesn't actually restart, same goes for when I click suspend.

here are my specs- hp-15-ba021ax

```
ram- 4gb
storage- crucial bx500 250 gb
processor- amd a10 9600p with integrated amd r5 graphics.
dedicated graphics- amd r7 m340
display- 1366x768
```

in the /etc/defult/grub file there is this line-

```
 GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nouveau.modeset=0"
```

even though there are no nvidia devices on my laptop

Comment: Are you running a supported release of Ubuntu? Read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting .

Answer (score 0):

the problems were solved by going to grub menu and setting 5.11.0-27-generic as the default kernel instead of 5.13.